# New SO user not agreeing with the guidelines

Tags: discussion, answers, new-users, users, duplicate-answers

I recently saw a [duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65433742/sum-values-inside-dictionary/65433814#answer-65433814) for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65433742/sum-values-inside-dictionary/65433814), so I left a comment:

> Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation (I am deleting other comments since they are not needed)

The user who posted the duplicate answer replied:

> Sorry I won't agree with you

What should I do in this case? Should I just forget about it, flag the comment, or something else.

Comment: Off-topic, but a question that gets 8 answers in a matter of minutes is bound to be a duplicate asked a thousand times before, as it was the case. You should first find appropriate duplicates, before answering. I find it weird that even 2 high-rep users answered

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It's Python - every man and his dog and their dog's dog is using it, which means the average level of quality is about 1km below the Earth's crust.

Comment: "Should I just forget about it.." Downvote and move on is kind of the mantra of this place.

Comment: '  I find it weird that even 2 high-rep users answered', I don't - answering mega-dupe low fruit is how they got that high rep:(

Comment: @IanKemp Like I don't run out of (down)/(close) votes in the [tag:c#] tag often... :)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto unless you're familiar with the duplicate, often it's easier and faster to just answer rather than trying to find a duplicate.  I've done that a few times before.

Comment: @MarkRansom: _"it's easier and faster to just answer rather than trying to find a duplicate"_ -- and yet, that sort of selfish lazy behavior is entirely against the community guidelines. If you care about the quality of the site, don't encourage lazy questions by providing lazy answers. Find the duplicate, vote to close.

Comment: @PeterDuniho sometimes you just don't know there's a duplicate if you haven't seen it before.  That's why I qualified with "unless you're familiar with the duplicate".  I'm of the opinion that having duplicate questions and answers aren't as bad as they're made out to be, because of different search terms and thought processes.

Comment: @MarkRansom: being familiar with a duplicate isn't any sort of reason to not find the duplicate. After all, if it were, the site policy would be to not bother with a search at all, since authors of questions can be assumed to not be familiar with any duplicate that answers there question. The logic behind a presumed need to be familiar with the duplicate is completely flawed.

Comment: "To the dungeon with ye!"

Comment: @PeterDuniho That’s an absolutist stance, which makes it plain unreasonable. I agree that in a perfect world it would be ideal if everybody always looked for *and found* relevant duplicates, and only then started answering. But declaring that any answer on a duplicate is bad, lazy, or somehow even maliciously playing the system is clearly going *(way)* too far. In practice Mark is right that finding the right duplicate is often not trivial, unless you already know exactly what you’re looking for, and rather than ignoring such questions answering them is clearly the better outcome.

Comment: There are times when I see a question and I know the probability of it being a duplicate is very high but I still answer the question as if I never seen anything like it before.

Comment: The rep system unfortunately rewards the folks answering these types of questions. There's almost no reward or recognition for cleanup duty (e.g. duplicate finding, closing, editing), so it's kind of no wonder that this happens so frequently, particularly in a place like [tag:python].

Comment: I guess their reply probably annoyed you - quite understandibly for a vareity of obvious reasons (to us rational people at least). If that's true just let it go, you did the right thing.

Comment: Writing "Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer..." might appear to be an attempt to be representing not just the community but SO-the-company because of the use of "we".

Comment: That answer was posted **within 10 minutes** of the earliest answer and less than 15 minutes after the question was posted. It's fair to say they probably started writing their answer before any of the others similar ones were posted, so I tend not to judge those too harshly. I dislike duplication, but I also don't want to punish people (either with downvotes or by forcing them to discard an answer they already started/finished writing) for something there's no way they could've known. We have enough of a problem with people posting answers **years** after similar ones were posted.

Comment: If I were to have left a comment, I would probably have said their answer would be better received and get more upvotes if they were to provide some explanation, links or additional context on top of just the code. This is exactly what the higher rep users (16k and 110k) did in their answers to that question. I might mention that this could help set their answer apart from the other ones (without any mention of which answer was posted first), but really code-only answers are not great regardless of whether there are any other answers.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

As a reviewer, it isn't your job to convince other users, or even to argue with them. Please leave that to diamond moderators.

You may, as in this case, choose to leave a comment explaining your concerns with the post and suggestions for improvement, but you should not allow yourself to get into a protracted discussion or argument. In most cases, you should not even engage further after leaving the initial comment. The only time I would recommend replying is if the person asks you a genuine question; e.g., seeking clarification on the policy, asking you to review their latest edits, etc. If they want to nitpick or argue, just bow out—that's not going to go anywhere productive, and we don't need a long, acrimonious comment thread as the cherry on top of a low-quality answer...

For answers that do not meet our minimum standards and need to be deleted, you can raise either a "very low quality" or "not an answer" flag on them. There's not even any need to leave a comment in these cases.

For answers with problems that are a little less obvious, you can raise a custom "needs moderator attention" flag. This will give you a textbox where you can provide a detailed description of your concerns about the post. It seems you did that in this case, but your message was only "duplicate answer". A moderator reviewed and declined your flag, asking "Duplicate of which answer?" If you're going to request that a late answer is fundamentally a repost of an existing answer, you need to tell which answer it is duplicating, ideally by providing a link to the other answer.

If you *did* get into a discussion with a user in the comments, then it ended up turning into an argument or was otherwise unproductive, you can go ahead and flag those comments for removal, too. It happens to all of us sometimes.

---

In this particular case, I've located the previous answer that one is duplicating. Since it is an *exact* duplicate (code blocks are identical, sans whitespace) that truly adds nothing new to the discussion, I've gone ahead and deleted it. I also removed all of the comments, replacing them with one of my own. If there is to be any backlash, I'd prefer that a moderator be the target of it, rather than you (or any other reviewer).

Comment: Looking at the user, they've provided 30 answers in less than 48 hours, and looking at some random 6-8 of them they look *very* bad quality ("here you go" + block of code + explanations in comments when requested). I'm tempted to raise a mod flag, but I'm unsure if I should

Comment: Always ask yourself, "what would I want a moderator to do about this?", and then include that request in the moderator flag. (Or, use it to decide not to raise a flag.) If the answers should be deleted, then a mod flag is appropriate.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The answer is *always* to raise a mod flag. Trust your gut - if it feels bad, it probably is.

Comment: Thanks both. I've raised the flag, as otherwise it would be seen as targeted downvoting/deletion voting .. :)

Comment: This is one of the best answers I have ever read on Meta. I have to say, I am guilty of falling into those back and forth. Good advice in this answer, both of Stack Exchange, and life really.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto can you provide a link to the user profile?

Comment: @zixuan I could, but I'd rather not throw more people at that user, this meta post is more than enough, their answers are already piling downvotes and deletion votes - if someone else thinks it's sensible to provide a direct link to the user, they can do so

Comment: _"There's not even any need to leave a comment in these cases."_. I partially agree with you but they need to know what's wrong with their question or answer right? For them to be able to correct it.

Comment: @CoolCloud The system will automatically provide a link to [this Help Center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) whenever an answer that has been flagged as NAA or VLQ is deleted by a moderator. This provides an answer to that question, and does so in an official manner, which is preferred over an off-the-cuff comment. Furthermore, it's possible that a user's diagnosis of VLQ or NAA is wrong (as mods, we see a lot of invalid flags of these types), and so I'd prefer that comments *not* be left as a matter of course when raising a flag, lest they provide wrong advice.

Comment: In the meantime, it's been 5 days since my flag, it's still pending and the user continues to post c**p :/

Comment: Yes, @Camilo, custom flags have a long backlog on Stack Overflow. That's not really new.

Answer (score 24):

Users don't get to "disagree" with the rules, regardless of how new they are or aren't to the site. If they disagree, they need to not use SO. Cody has already dealt with this particular instance, but looking at the user's account, it seems their primary activity is posting maybe-answers to low-quality questions - most of which have already been closed as unanswerable.

I think some additional moderation effort would be well spent on reminding this user not to answer bad questions.

Comment: Here in Germany, there is a group that argues that the transfer of power from Adolf Hitler to his successor did not follow the rules of the Nazi Party, therefore all agreements made with the Allies are invalid because the person making those agreements did not have the authority to enter in those agreements, therefore the Federal Republic of Germany does not exist, therefore, they do not need to pay taxes. Guess what? They still go to prison for tax evasion. You can disagree with the rules all you want, that doesn't make the rules go away.

Comment: I'm going to guess that telling this user not to answer bad questions will fail, because they don't sound like the kind of person who would recognize a bad question.  If you can recognize a bad question, you should be able to recognize that your own answer is bad too.

Comment: Note that the comments the OP is asking about are sufficiently unclear that the user might not disagree with the rules in general, but just the "*your answer does not provide additional value over existing ones*" part.

Comment: @Bergi As they say, "s**t sucks".

Comment: Now, that's a beautiful comment by @Jörg, what an Instant Classic, should be immortalized, receive bounties, everything! <slow-clap.jpg>

Answer (score -5):

> The person who posted the duplicate answer replied: "Sorry I won't agree with you"

This text does not indicate what exactly that person is disagreeing with. Perhaps they simply believe that their answer is worth keeping? It's a vague sentence.

...

looking at the linked question and answers to get some context, it seems *everything* was deleted eventually. So, "garbage in garbage out"? It's probably not a good idea to discuss in principle the notion of uses disagreeing with site policies based on such an example.

Answer (score -10):

I think you invested too much effort into a single-time visitor. Furthermore, using the site, at least partially he has to agree its rules. But he did not deny the rules of the site, he rejected your opinion. He did not know that it is not only an opinion, but you also have power over his content.

The user did not know the rules. Probably he did not know what means closure, he did not know that he has some chance to reopen (but it is not a big problem because the reopen review queue is ruled by always "leave closed"-clickers).

The correct way is this:

1. Editing the post to make it clear that it is not dupe, *in a single edit* (because only the first edit starts the reopen vote).
2. Best if the edited post uses the dupe origin as reference. Roughly so:

> "This question (link) mentions a similar problem, and on the answers, I tried to do this (explanation). But it does not work, because (explanation)."

Now the problem is that the user did not know also these.

In general, it is problematic to enforce rules what the users do not know.

This is not your fault, this is the fault of the system. Otherways the system has no way to inject the required StackExchange skills into all the visitors already before their first post.

Not seeing the question/answer, it is hard to say, what should have been done. We have too less reviewers, this is the source of all problem.

Comment: Yes, the site is pretty poor at making users acquainted with the rules, but unfortunately that is not something we can do anything about. All we can do is enforce those rules to the best of our ability.

Comment: @IanKemp Yes, we can: instead silent down-close-del votes, users could get some advice, particularly if their future contributions look useful.